# CIFilters for compositing Red, Green, and Blue color channels

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-image

I am building a "Curves" editor for an image and would like to split out each color channel to run through the `CIToneCurve` filter before compositing them back together into a single color image. (I'm aware of the `CIColorCurves` filter, but that doesn't give me the control I want.)

I am able to separate the channels using three separate `CIColorCube` filters to generate the 3 separate color channels, but I'm not sure how to put them back together to form a single color image.

Using the `maximumCompositingFilter` and `minimumCompositing` filters works, but when I run the individual color photos through the ToneCurve, adjusting the highs or the lows (depending on which compositing filter I used) messes up the colors.

Comment: Have you tried simple additive blending? If the separated images still have their color values in their respective channels, adding them together should yield the full RGB image again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the suggestion posted by Frank Schlegel and using simple additive compositing. I had to write my own CIFilter to do that, but it was quite simple.

```
half4 rgbaComposite(sample_h redColor, sample_h greenColor, sample_h blueColor, sample_h alphaColor) {
        return half4(redColor.r, greenColor.g, blueColor.b, alphaColor.a);
}
```

This is for a metal backed CIFilter. Each input assumes that it only contains a single color channel.

Comment: Are you sure the effect is same as in Photoshop or Photos app of Mac? RGB composite is not simply superposition of red, green, and blue. You can have curves for each r,g,b as well as rgb composite curve.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with Accelerate.vImage.

Apple has an article that discusses converting an interleaved image to separate planar buffers: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/optimizing_image_processing_performance

...and there's an article that discusses vImage / Core Image interoperability using `CIImageProcessorKernel`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/reading_from_and_writing_to_core_video_pixel_buffers. I can't remember if `CIImageProcessorKernel` supports single channel 8-bit images such as [`R8`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciformat/1437695-r8).

...also, this Apple sample code project may be of interest: [Applying Tone Curve Adjustments to Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/applying_tone_curve_adjustments_to_images).